# How to Download all Data from tables from a vf page

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning

I got a requirement to get data from all the tables present in the vf page for example: we have 100 records, i have customized page into a list view with 10 records per page. Now i have a button called Export, by clicking on that button i need to download all 100 records, as a csv file.please help on this guys

Note: Exporting data without using jquery.

Comment: Seems like this would be a trivial problem for a controller or extension. What have you tried so far?

Comment: as of now i have done like getting data from single table. i.e(out of 100 records i can export 10 from each table this all done through javascript) now i am trying to export all records which all present in the page tables. can you please help me if u have any idea.

Comment: Like I said, this should be trivial using your page's controller (or extension). If you're doing pagination, you must be querying all your data somewhere. Generating a CSV from your data is simply iterating over your results, adding field values to a string, and adding commas as appropriate. I'd suggest doing some research on your own. Once you have a basic implementation, you can come back here and ask for help on specific parts that you're stuck on.

Comment: thanks Derek for your responce and suggestions. i will try